# Why doesn't the graph of radial part of wavefunction of 2p orbital change its sign?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orbitals

Below I have given the graphs of radial part of the wave functions of $\mathrm{2s}$ and $\mathrm{2p}$ orbitals respectively.

The graph of the $\mathrm{2s}$ orbital makes sense. It has a radial node and about that radial node the wave function changes its sign. We can also see this in the actual diagram of the wave function of $\mathrm{2s}$ orbital.

But I am slightly confused with the graph of the radial part of wave function of the $\mathrm{2p}$ orbital. We know that $\mathrm{2p}$ orbital has two lobes. For instance, if we take $\mathrm{2p_x}$ orbital, it has two lobes, one lobe in the positive side of the $x$-axis and another lobe in the negative side of the $x$-axis. Thus the $2p$ orbital wavefunction clearly changes its sign about the origin of the $x$-axis. It changes from positive to negative sign at some point. Then why is the radial part of the wavefunction of the $\mathrm{2p}$ orbital showing that it is not changing its sign at any point?

Why is the radial part of the wave function showing us that the $\mathrm{2p}$ orbital never changes its sign? It clearly does. Can someone please explain?

[image: Graphs of the radial part of the wave functions]

Comment: First, consider what you have plotted. You plot R as a function of r. How is your x-axis supposed to differentiate between the top lobe of your 2p orbital and your bottom lobe, which both have *the same values of r* (but different values of $\theta$ and $\phi$? The next question you may want to consider is: the wavefunction is R (radial part) times Y (angular part). Which of these two parts is *actually* contributing the minus sign to the wavefunction in the other lobe? Is it R or Y?

Answer (score 1):

> The wave function of one of the lobes is positive and the wave function of the other lobe is negative. Then why doesn't this change of sign get reflected in the graph of the radial part of the wave function of 2p orbital

You are exactly right. But just imagine how can only the radial part differentiate between the two lobes of, let's say for consistency, the $\mathrm{p}$ orbital. Each lobe of the $\mathrm{p}$ orbital has same radial distance from the origin and thus their difference cannot be judged by the radial part of the wavefunction.

To account for this change in sign you have to look at the complete wavefunction which also takes into account $\theta$ and $\phi$.

For example look at the radial wavefunction diagram and the orbital contour diagram of $\mathrm{2p}$ orbital from *Radial and Angular Parts of Atomic Orbitals<sup>[[1]](https://chem.libretexts.org/@go/page/1712)</sup>*

Radial wavefunction(green curve):
[image: 2p radial wavefunction]

Contour diagram:
[image: 2p contour diagram]

As can be seen from the diagrams, for a given $r$ and $\phi$, $\theta$ is the deciding factor whether the sign is positive or negative.

So to account for the complete characteristics of an orbital you have to take into account the *complete* wavefunction and not it's part.

---

But now you might ask why the radial part of the $\mathrm{2s}$ orbital does describe the change in its sign.

The answer is that $\mathrm s$ orbitals are radially symmetrical and thus their wavefunctions are independent of $\theta$ and $\phi$, leaving only $r$ as the parameter which can lead to the change in sign.

---

**Reference:**

<sup>[(1)](https://chem.libretexts.org/@go/page/1712)   Libretexts. Radial and angular parts of atomic orbitals https://chem.libretexts.org/@go/page/1712 (accessed Jun 19, 2021).</sup>